# The mouse is invisible

Tags: mouse

I can’t add a photo, as the is no mouse to take a photo of...
It appears if I boot in safe mode. ONE of the problems is trying to fix it, without a mouse...
Clean install, on a Dell R420.
I’ve tried the X11 Xorg.conf attempt but it hanged on trying to install Gedit.

Comment: The mouse still exists - it clicks and selects, and moves, but I can’t see it, and have to play Marco-Polo with it trying to click my way around the screen.